# How to read a random text file from the assets folder when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app that will present a random text file each time the button is pressed. I've figured out how to get a single text file from the asset folder but I can't figure out how to make the app choose one at random. What do I need to add to allow this?

I'm sort of new to this and have been trying to find an explanation for a while now with no luck so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button random_story;

TextView story_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    random_story = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_story);

    story_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_text);

    random_story.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = "";
            try {
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("1.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                text = new String(buffer);
            } catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            story_text.setText(text);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Currently the code always gets "1.txt". The assets folder includes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. and I'd like the button press to choose one of them at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random and use it

```
Random r = new Random();
int fileStart = 1; // if first file name is 1.text
int fileEnd = 11; // if last file name is 10.txt
int randomFile = r.nextInt(fileEnd - fileStart) + fileStart;
```

Now use it

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(randomFile + ".txt");
```

**Note:** This solution would work only if file names are in a sequence.

Comment: My hero. I knew it would be a reasonably simple solution but I just didn't know what to look for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class and generate a number between 1 and the end:

Where 5 is the maximum, and 1 is the minimum, the format is:

```
nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(5 - 1 + 1) + 1;
InputStream is = getAssets().open(num + ".txt");
```

Or if the numbers themselves are random, add them to a `List` and get a random number from that `List`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(7);
list.add(9);

Random random = new Random();
int num = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
```